# What does "limited as it is" mean?

Tags: phrases

I was reading an article on Forbes, but I couldn't fully understand the bold expression in the paragraph below.

> Of course, China’s growth rate still makes it among the fastest-expanding economies in the world, so the recent slowdown can hardly be termed a crisis. And the shift away from China, **limited as it is** began before the trade war, spurred on by rising prices and intellectual property theft. As too did the nation’s transition from reliance on cheap manufacturing to the production of higher value-added goods.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It’s saying that the shift away from China is limited, but began before. Did you leave out a comma after is?

Comment: I checked the website again, no punctuation was missed. And thank you very much for your answer, now I understand what it's talking about. : )

Comment: It means ....And the shift away from China, which is currently seen limited, began...

Comment: @Sam If there's no comma there, it's a mistake in the original text, as this is always a parenthetical remark.

Answer (score 1):

A parenthetical phrase of the form ***adjective*** as it is mainly means that the subject is **adjective**, but is often used to minimize the impact that it has on whatever is being discussed.

So the statement is saying that there was a limited (small) shift away from China that began before the trade war, but it hasn't prevented China from having one of the fastest growing economies in the world.

Another example of this would be

> As strong as he is, he still can't lift 1000 pounds.